# Eclipse javaw.exe hanging at startup (49% cpu), regardless of task

Tags: eclipse, javaw

It was hanging on refreshing workspacing, specifically refreshing files in /target/classes in a project. I renamed that folder and now it hanging on the next progress item: Initializing Java Tooling.

I a unable to start elcipse. If clicking on expanding one of the projects in project view, it stops responding and javaw.exe needs to be killed.

This is on Windows XP

This is Eclipse Indigo

Comment: It looks to be completely broken. I've never had it hang on projects like this. I've started removing projects and javaw.exe is still handing on projects with barely any contents.

Answer (score 1):

This may help

In your eclipse,

1) Go to Help

2) Click Eclipse marketplace

3) search - optimizer

install "optimizer for eclipse"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works (the first AND second method)

http://blog.tauren.com/2009/10/repairing-corrupt-eclipse-workspace.html

You are one cheeky mate I swear eclipse

Comment: Nvm, it doesn't work. I need help. I removed the metadata and started importing projects. On importing the third maven project, javaw.exe is using 50% cpu again and is stuck on 10% at Importing Maven Projects.

Comment: Wow, okay I'm getting closer to the root of the problem. I woke up with a bluescreen which is not uncommon for whatever reason (truecrypt probably). Apparently in this project's classes folder, a package folder is being displayed by windows as having an ever increasing number of files (when viewing folder properties, the files never stop growing) with the size on disk being thousands of terrabytes. It's not possible to delete this folder or view its contents.